# Can't connect to graphql after sending a bad schema to graphql/idl endpoint

Tags: neo4j, graphql

I can't connect to my graphql endpoint after sending a bad schema to graphql/idl endpoint. I tried restarting the neo4j server but no luck. Has anyone run into this problem and can help or will I have to do a fresh install?[error when I try to call graphql.schema() on the neo4j browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4Abx.png)

Comment: Did you try passing a new schema with the [`graphql.idl()` procedure?](https://github.com/neo4j-graphql/neo4j-graphql#uploading-a-schema)

Comment: @WilliamLyon Unfortunately that's what broke it in the first place. I might be submitting an invalid schema? Would you happen to have an example of valid schema; from my research it looks like the schema I have is right

Comment: Can you share the GraphQL schema you are using? Here's an [example schema](https://github.com/neo4j-graphql/neo4j-graphql/tree/3.3#uploading-a-schema)

Answer (score 0):

Create or recreate a valid schema:

```
CALL graphql.idl('
type Movie  {
  title: String!
  released: Int
  actors: [Person] @relation(name:"ACTED_IN",direction:IN)
}
type Person {
  name: String!
  born: Int
  movies: [Movie] @relation(name:"ACTED_IN")
}
')
```

and then create your own schema.

Works for me.
Hope this help.